# TypeScript Unexpected Ideentifier

Tags: node.js, typescript

I my code is like the below but i couldn't work on my function because of Unexpected Identifier error.

```
type List= Folder[];
type Folder = {
  id:string,
  name:string
  files:File[]
}
type File ={
  id:string,
  name:string
}

const listA:List = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
  },
]

export default function move(list: List,source: string, destination: string): List {
  //throw new Error('Not implemented');
  return list;
}
move(listA,"4","6");
```

When i run my code this error is displays:

```
type List= Folder[];
     ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)[39m
[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)[39m
[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47[39m
```

Can you explain me that why am i getting this error and is there a way to fix that

Comment: also try this: type List = Array<Folder>

Comment: Also tried that, fol List and Folder. Can you check my type declaration for listA is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to compile the file and are trying to run the `.ts` file instead of the resulting `.js` file.

If you want to do this manually:

`tsc <your-file>.ts && node <your-file>.js`

However, I recommend using [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), allowing you to simply run:

`ts-node <your-file>.ts`

Comment: I am already using manual method for running my code on Node. I just tried ts-node version too but it didn't helped. :(

Comment: Can you try to run my code in your computer?

Comment: Yep, works fine on my machine and also here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-node-forked-tm3l9

Comment: I see, so code is fine, it probably caused by a problem in my machine.

Comment: Do you have a `.tsconfig` file? Maybe there's some misconfiguration that causes this.

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
I couldn't find a misconfiguration, can you check it too.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? E.g. through github?